# Cannot Disable Button from being pressed

Tags: javascript, uibutton, pug, getelementbyid

I'm creating front end code that plays a game of Black Jack.  When the user hits the hit me button, the user draws a card.  I'm trying to make it though that if the user draws a card that puts them over a value of 21, then the hit me button is disabled.  Yet for whatever reason the button is not being disabled.

Javascript:

```
if (sum > 21) {
      acePresent = checkAces(array); //checks the array of cards for any aces, If so change value of ace from 11 to 1.
      if (acePresent) {
        sum = sum - 10;
      } else {
        console.log("No aces and player has busted.  Disabling hit me button");
        document.getElementById("drawcards").disabled = true;
      }
```

PUG file:

```
#endturn.ui.red.button
    |   Stay
#drawcards.ui.green.button
    |   Hit Me
```

Comment: Try debugging, if your code reaches the else statement or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable a button with JS, you can use

`document.getElementById("drawcards").setAttribute('disabled', true);`

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

The other parts of logic depends on you, but some suggestions:
Does your checkAces return with a boolean?
Does checkAces return with the correct value?
Does checkAces synchronous?

Try debugging, why does the function not reach the else statement.

Comment: Doesn't work.  I've tried that.  Also yes checkAces returns a boolean.  It essentially iterates through the array of the player's cards for any aces.  If it finds one, it minuses the player's score by 10 and alters the value of the card to be "RESOLVED".  That way when the score is evaluated again, all cards with a value of "RESOLVED" only add one to the score.

Comment: Also it reaches the else statement because the console.log() statement gets printed.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Does your document.getElementById finds the button you are looking for?

Comment: I just did console.log() on the document.getElementByID and it returns this <div class="ui green button" id="drawcards" disabled="true">  Hit Me</div>.  I think for whatever reason, it's disabled on default and I have to enable it to prevent from pushing it

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.  The issue was that I needed to add the class "disabled" to the button.  The correct Javascript code to do so is this:

```
document.getElementById("drawcards").classList.add("disabled");
```